# Perizzite and Canaanite Difference

Tags: history

I want to know the difference between Canaanite and Perizzite. I know that they lived in the land of Canaan before the Israelites, however, I want to know what makes them different. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Rashi (Exodus 13:5) quoting the Mechilta  says that All of the nations in Israel prior to Jews settling there were Canaanites  and descendants of Canaan. That it is why it referred to as Eretz Canaan. However when being referred to as separate nations  only one of them retained the name Canaan/Canaanite.

Just a guess. They always had their family  differences. The  others went off to explore other areas and established independent governments and cultures there whereas the Canaanite tribe remained in original place of settlement and retained the original culture.

The Preezey were possibly the first break off group because in Genesis 13:7 there is a reference to only those two groups  (or perhaps they were the only two groups living in close proximity of Abraham and Lot)

There is no  known group with clear historical records still extant that are  referred to as the Preezey but there is speculation about certain groups only known through archeological  research that they were the Preezey who the Bible refers to

Answer (score -1):

What makes all the nations of the time different is descent. They were more like large tribes that descended from different people.